# (kill-emacs) not working

Tags: ubuntu, emacs24

I've seen the discussion on how to kill the emacs daemon after killing the client. If you run emacs as a daemon, killing it's client doesn't also kill the daemon: the daemon just sits there still running. All/most solutions I've seen involve (kill-emacs). For example, I have this alias:

```
alias killemacs='emacsclient -e "(kill-emacs)"'
```

. . . and I'm pretty sure it used to work. But now it has no effect. Now I have to resort to kill -9 . Any thoughts as to the *definitive* way to kill a emacs daemon per command line?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe that:

```
kill -9 `ps aux | grep emacs | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}'`
```

Comment: Yes, this worked. Thanks. Still confused why (kill-emacs) isn't working.

Answer (score -1):

use `ps` to get process id of emacs and then use `kill -9 <pid>`

Comment: Isn’t that _exactky_ what the answer from a decade ago does, but with an actual command to show how to do it?

Comment: i am sorry , i am new here